# How does Mercy remove conditions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin, conditions, healing

Is the creature affected by a Paladin's Mercy, immune from contracting the conditions another time during the duration of the hour long ability? (because those conditions wouldn't actually get eliminated but simply removed for an hour, according to Mercy's description)

Does that mean that stacking effects like fear do stack even on a creature affected by Mercy (because those conditions are still there, they simply don't show any symptoms) and can therefore produce worse conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mercy does not confer any kind of immunity. It removes conditions already present, but the target may well gain them again. For example, if a paladin with the Fatigued mercy uses *lay on hands* on their barbarian ally who has stopped raging, that barbarian will no longer be fatigued—and if an enemy witch uses *touch of fatigue* on the barbarian the very next round, that barbarian will be fatigued again.

The description of mercy does mention something about “1 hour,” but this is only for special cases where the mercy removes a condition but not an underlying effect causing that condition. For example, if a paladin has the Enfeebled mercy, but not the Poisoned mercy, and uses *lay on hands* on an ally poisoned with [king’s sleep](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/king-s-sleep), that ally is no longer drained of 1 Constitution, but they are still poisoned. An hour later, the king’s sleep kicks back in, and then they are drained 1 Constitution again. But anything else (including a fresh dose of king’s sleep) during that hour can still drain their Constitution.